# Staging syntax error while creating Django model instance

Tags: django, bash

```
from customer.models import Customer; cust = Customer.objects.create_user(first_name=\"'$first_name'\", last_name='\"'$last_name'\", uuid='\"'$uuid'\");
```

Getting these errors for the last name:
Staging: -c: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
Staging: -c: syntax error: unexpected end of file

I have tried last_name='$last_name' but that does not work and I need it to still be a string if given an empty string. This is in a bash script.

Comment: Why are the double quotes escaped in `first_name=\"'first_name'\"`? You can simply write `"'first_name'"`

Comment: These are variables. I updated it.